# Create custom control with some property set through xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a custom control, deriving from a UserControl, it has a textblock, a textbox and 2 buttons, called PathMng.

```
<Grid>
    <!-- some other stuff -->
    <TextBlock Name="PathName">Name</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to set the TextBlock's text through an external xaml calling this control

```
<Grid>
    <local:PathMng>NameHere</local:PathMng>
</Grid>
```

But I couldn't understand what do I have to do to bind the text "NameHere" to the TextBlock.

I tried to search with the words "custom xaml", "template xaml" or maybe-too-much-generic-words, but I couldn't find what I'm needed

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to make it simpler for you, set it using, for example:

```
<local:PathMng MyText="NameHere"/>
```

Now, in your user control code-behind, create a dependency property:

```
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(UserContrrol1), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Finally, in your UserControl1 XAML, bind your TextBox's Text property to this DP:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}}" />
```

All this assumes your user control is called UserControl1

Comment: This worked, thanks! But I have the impression it seems a bit complex, I thought there would have been some other easier ways

Comment: @user1722791 - dude, this is pretty simple - use the propdp snippet to create the dependency property. It's completely reusable, bindable. Totally the best way :)